# Determine last invocation of callback

Tags: c++, sqlite

In c++, using sqlite3, a callback function is used to retrieve select results from the database:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, callback, 0, &sqlErrorMsg);
```

With each record returned from the database this function is called:

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    std::cout << "Called\n";
    for(i = 0;i < argc;i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");

    /** Example **/
    //if(last) do something; //to demonstrate that I need access to this information inside of the callback
    return 0;
}
```

I need a way to determine the last call to this function (on the last record of sql).

I assumed it would take some minds more experienced in c++. I'm still somewhat of a novice, so tips are always welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run a separate query to get the count, and pass it as the user-data argument to the callback. Then keep a counter in the callback and when it's equal to the value passed as the user-data then you have the last record.

Comment: I thought of something similar but didn't know how to pass other arguments to the callback or that argument

Comment: It's very easy if you use e.g. the [`sqlite3_exec`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) function.

Comment: Snap that's awesome. I hadn't come across that example of sqlite3_exec before. I'm under a tough deadline and hadn't used sqlite3 before, but the syntax is almost identical to mysql, so I used it to save time. Just had to skim tutorials though, so I missed that. Thanks very much. Post as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (with help from ):

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)rowCount, &zErrMsg);
```

Then in the callback

```
static callback(void* rowCount, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) { //here the integer is converted to hex, but converting it is easy enough
}
```